# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: variable substitution

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

Given:

```
MyObject *object1 = [MyObject createWithName:@"name1"];
MyObject *object2 = [MyObject createWithName:@"name2"];
MyObject *object3 = [MyObject createWithName:@"name3"];

NSArray *myArray = @[object1, object2, object3];
NSString *name = @"name1";
```

Doing

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == '%@'", name];
NSArray *filtered = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Leaves me with

```
filtered.count == 0
```

but

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:"name == '%@'",name]];
NSArray *filtered = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

leaves me with

```
[filtered objectAtIndex:0] == object1
```

Why? This seems like an odd behavior for predicateWithFormat.  Does NSPredicate's definition of format vary from NSLog/NSString? I couldn't find anything obvious in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but in the first predicate, you shouldn't have the single quotes around @. That makes it a literal, so you're filtering on "@" not name.

Comment: You do know the answer to the question!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the second version works, but the reason your first version doesn't work is the single quotes around the @. This makes @ a literal, so you're actually filtering for name == @, which is not what you want. Just remove the single quotes, and it will work.